# Codeigniter get sum of goals a player has made

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I got a database. This is the mysql script of it. A player can appear more in the table what I want to do is get the sum of all the goals this player has made.

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spelerswedstrijden` (
`Id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`spelerId` int(2) NOT NULL,
`wedstrijdId` int(5) NOT NULL,
`goals` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`assisten` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`gelekaarten` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`rodekaarten` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
 )
```

My Model code:

```
function getGoals($id) {

    $this->db->where('spelerId', $id);
    $this->db->from('spelerswedstrijden');
    $goals = $this->db->select_sum('goals');;

    return $goals;
}
```

Using this code gives me following error: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_driver could not be converted to string
Any Ideas how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getGoals($id) 
{
    $this->db->select('COUNT(id) as TotalGoals');
    $this->db->where('spelerId', $id);
    $this->db->group_by('spelerId');
    $goals = $this->db->get('goals');;
    return $goals->row();
}
```

In controller access it like this

```
$result = $this->mymodel->getGoals($id); 
echo $result->TotalGoals;
```

Comment: This one returns me an array

Comment: +1 but with one small correction:
`if($goals->num_rows>0) {return $goals->row();} else {return 0;}`

Comment: I have it like this:
function getGoals($id) {
        $this->db->select('COUNT(id) as TotalGoals');
        $this->db->where('spelerId', $id);
        $this->db->group_by('spelerId');
        $goals = $this->db->get('spelerswedstrijden');
        
        return $goals->row();
    }
In my other model
$result = $this->spelerswedstrijden_model->getGoals($speler->Id);
            $speler->goals = $result->TotalGoals;
It should return 5 but instead it returns 2 I think that is because I have 2 rows for that id in the database.

Comment: I found it the first line should of been
$this->db->select('SUM(goals) as TotalGoals');
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
function getGoals($id) {

    $this->db->select_sum('goals');
    $this->db->where('spelerId', $id);
    $this->db->from('spelerswedstrijden');
    $goals = $this->db->get();

    return $goals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Appraoch:

```
 $this->db->select('sum(goals) AS total_goals');
```